# Flutter Streambuilder too fast when using with Dismissible

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream, dismissible

I am using Streambuilder for streaming data from Cloud Firestore and I am displaying the data with Dismissibles using Listview Builder.

Now when I dismiss a Dismissible, it pops up again for a short time until it is deleted form the database.

Has anyone experienced the same and knows how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!